# Bootloader Jumps Successfully But Firmware Doesnt Start

Tags: c, stm32, bootloader

Im trying to start the firmware located at address 0x08019000 inside my Flash, but even after making a successfully jump to the address, the firmware doesnt respond.

Im using the HSDatalog firmware from ST, which can be downloaded from github [here](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/fp-sns-datalog1/tree/main). As microcontroller i use the STEVAL-STWINKT1B evaluation board with 2MB FLASH and 640KB RAM. My bootloader is successfully  jumping to each flashed firmware that i use in my project, hence the it's code is not an issue. However, the firmware from ST seems "stuck" after i get to a task scheduler loop inside it and i can't understand why. Its main looks like this

```
int main(void) {
    HAL_Init();

    SystemClock_Config();

    /* Enable Power Clock*/
    __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
    HAL_PWREx_EnableVddUSB();
    HAL_PWREx_EnableVddIO2();
    BSP_Enable_DCDC2();

    OTA_Verify_Current_Active_Bank();

    /* Configure the Battery Charger */
//  BattChrg_Init(); not needed

    /* Configure Power Voltage Detector(PVD) to detect if battery voltage is low */
//  PVD_Config(); not needed

    /* Configure DEBUG PIN and LED */
    BSP_DEBUG_PIN_Init_All();
    BSP_LED_Init(LED_GREEN);
    BSP_LED_Init(LED_ORANGE);
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* Initialize srand() using STM32 TRNG peripheral */
    RND_Init();

    HSD_JSON_set_allocation_functions(HSD_malloc, HSD_free);

    /* Start USB */
    MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
    HAL_Delay(100);

    HSD_DeviceDescriptor_Init_t deviceDescriptorInit;

    /* Set default device description */
    strcpy(deviceDescriptorInit.alias, "STWIN_001");
    strcpy(deviceDescriptorInit.model, "STEVAL-STWINKT1B");
    strcpy(deviceDescriptorInit.partNumber, "FP-SNS-DATALOG1");
    strcpy(deviceDescriptorInit.URL, "www.st.com/stwin");
    strcpy(deviceDescriptorInit.fwName, "FP-SNS-DATALOG1_Datalog1");
    strcpy(deviceDescriptorInit.bleMacAddress, "00:00:00:00:00:00");
    char tmp1[6] = {
    HSD_VERSION_MAJOR, '.',
    HSD_VERSION_MINOR, '.',
    HSD_VERSION_PATCH, '\0' };
    strcpy(deviceDescriptorInit.fwVersion, tmp1);
    set_device_description(&deviceDescriptorInit);

    /* Populate the sensor database and enable all sensors */
    Create_Sensors();

    /* Initialize tags */
    HSD_TAGS_init(COM_GetDevice());

    /* USER Button initialization */
    BSP_PB_Init(BUTTON_USER, BUTTON_MODE_EXTI);
    BSP_PB_PWR_Init();

    /* Sensor Manager initialization */
    SM_Peripheral_Init();
    SM_OS_Init();
    Peripheral_MSP_Init_All();

    /* SD card Manager initialization */
    SDM_Peripheral_Init();

    /* Initialize sensors and SD card threads */
    Peripheral_OS_Init_All();
    SDM_OS_Init();

    /* Initialize and allocate AutoMode thread */
    g_pxAMtaskObj = AMTaskAlloc();
    AMTaskInit(g_pxAMtaskObj);

    /* initialize and allocate BLE thread */
#if (HSD_BLE_ENABLE == 1)
    BLE_CM_OS_Init();
#endif
    /* Start scheduler */
    **osKernelStart**();

    while (1)
        ;

}
```

- Bootloader program [here](https://pastebin.com/iemPNFLc)(Credit to [Akos Pasztor](https://akospasztor.com/projects/stm32-bootloader/))
- Bootloader usage in main.c [here](https://pastebin.com/BUabViuY)

Im invoking the *Enter_Bootloader* function after i successfully mounted an FatFS formated SD card. That function flashed my .bin onto the FLASH beginning at a specified address. Afterwards im jumping to the application using the *Bootloader_JumpToApplication* function.

Has anyone ideas why the firmware may get stuck? And has anyone used this firmware together with a bootloader to share his experience?

Comment: - HSDatalog linker settings [here](https://pastebin.com/cA7h9aA5)
- HSDatalog VTOR (system)settings [here](https://pastebin.com/ZYnTwaJ9)
- Bootloader linker settings [here](https://pastebin.com/TwB69MJR)
- Bootloader VTOR (system)settings [here](https://pastebin.com/T3Gq9X21)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any new information, don't add it in a comment. Ta! Also, please don't include links to external sites. If the information is text, please add it as text to the question. If it's an image, please add it as an inline image in the question.

Comment: _As microcontroller i use the STEVAL-STWINKT1B evaluation board_ That's not a microcontroller, that's a board. You should've said you're using STM32L4R9 on the STEVAL-STWINKT1B board. Check physically if it's this mcu indeed. Check if you compile specifically for this mcu.   _firmware located at address 0x08019000_ That's quite high. Does the firmware fit entirely? Blinky works? This firmware works without the bootloader? Debug as usually, find out what does the firmware do and where is it stuck.

Comment: _after making a successfully jump to the address_ How do you know? Simple blinky instead of target application works? Try replacing the bootloader with only a simple stub which does nothing else but jump to the target application possibly programmed using Cube Programmer or similar - this is to exclude or confirm bootloader as source of problem.

Comment: How exactly do you jump? In Cortex-M, if you want to execute function from address 0x12345678, you need to jump to 0x12345679 (least significant bit is always set and ignored for address resolving), which would indicate thumb instruction set, otherwise you get usagefault (potentially elevated to hardfault, I think). By the way, did you (OP) check any exception flags? What's the processor state upon your jump? Can you jump to that location through function pointer? Smth like `((void (*)(void))(jump_address | 0x01))();`